# Android HTTP PUT not sending JSON request to server resulting in HTTP 405 Method not allowed

Tags: android, json

Android HTTP PUT not sending JSON request to server resulting in HTTP 405 Method not allowed.

Below is my async task background code

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("URL");

            String jsonresponse = "";
            try {
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(resultPojo).toString());
                se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");//text/plain;charset=UTF-8
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

                httpPut.setEntity(se);
                httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                jsonresponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                System.out.println("res .... "+jsonresponse);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

serverside code :

```
@POST
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response submitUserResponse(@PathParam("userId") int userId,
            @PathParam("id") int id, List<ResultPojo> responses) {
            try {
            //core logic goes here
                        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
            }
```

Comment: you should be using retrofit2 its awesome

Comment: maybe your server route is another http request method

Comment: @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
both is json

Comment: your server what language it is in?

Comment: using Java rest APi

Comment: post it here then

Comment: update the question  can't post the exact code but u will get idea what i am trying to do

Comment: 405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs allow the POST method necessary to process the form.

Comment: A request method is not supported for the requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form that requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

Comment: thanks it got working. there is mismatch of PUT and POST at server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141919/discussion-between-remario-and-feroz-siddiqui).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright just like what was discussed it is most likely a mismatch different HTTP methods, in this case A Put and a post, whenever you ever encounter that HTTP code(405) do perform a validation on the methods you used, it happens.405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs allow the POST method necessary to process the form.A request method is not supported for the requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form that requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

Comment: i always do a method re validation just to be sure

Comment: sure, i got into the same mess once.just gave you a upvote